# How to read this complex Javascript shortcut operator?

Tags: javascript

I was diving into another developer's code and came across this crazy line. Looks like there's a bunch of comparisons going on but can't wrap my head around it.

```
num > -1 ? "down" === position && value >= this._offset ? this.hideFunc() : "up" === position && value >= this._offset && this.showFunc() : this.showFunc()
```

How can I decipher this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: This is horrible code.

Comment: Is applying a clueplank to said developer an option? To add insult to injury, I seem to recall that Javascript has different precedence rules for the `?:` operator than other languages with a C-like syntax, which means there's good odds the answers you're getting are plain wrong.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (num > -1) {
    if ( "down" === position && value >= this._offset ) {
       return this.hideFunc();
    } else if ("up" === position && value >= this._offset) {
       return this.showFunc();
    } else {
       return; //Doesn't exist in the one liner but the function must return something..
    }
} else {
    return this.showFunc();
}
```

Comment: Why put brackets in some places and not other? At least be consistent.

Comment: sometimes it is more readable with brackets (followed by many lines) and sometimes it is not (one line) that's all

Comment: And I would strongly encourage *you* to strongly encourage your colleague to refactor the code into this, so that it is more comprehensible. Clever use of ternary operators is not a virtue.

Comment: Actually, there's a missing `return false` in here (in an `else` in the first branch). The one-liner will definitely evaluate to *something*, whereas this code might now.

Answer (score 1):

[Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) tells us that the [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator) are the outermost, followed by ANDs and the comparisons. A better (clearer) way to write this would be

```
(num > -1)
  ? ( (("down" === position) && (value >= this._offset))
      ? this.hideFunc()
      : (("up" === position) && (value >= this._offset)) && this.showFunc() )
  : this.showFunc()
```

<sup>(The parenthesis were only added for unambiguousness, you might as well omit them - having enough information in the indentation)</sup>

Now you "only" need to know about the [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the AND operators to see that it's a complicated way of writing

```
if (num > -1)
    if (value >= this._offset) {
        if ("down" === position)
            this.hideFunc();
        else if ("up" === position)
            this.showFunc();
    }
else
    this.showFunc();
```

(and getting back the return value from the function invocations or `false`)

Comment: Nothing, if you ask me. I'm guessing somebody saw the first code block and downvoted (thinking you were recommending that) without reading the full answer. The internet's full of TL;DRers, you know!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it seems every other answer here has missed one potential branch in deconstructing the ternary operator.

```
if (num > -1) {
    if ( "down" === position && value >= this._offset ) {
       return this.hideFunc();
    } else if ("up" === position && value >= this._offset) {
       return this.showFunc();

    /*** HERE'S THE BRANCH OTHER ANSWERS MISS ***/
    } else {
       return false;
    }

} else {
    return this.showFunc();
}
```

This comes from this particular segment of the ghastly ternary expression in your question:

```
"up" === position && value >= this._offset && this.showFunc()
```

We can break this down into two branches:

```
"up" === position && value >= this._offset
```

Obviously that expression is actually two branches as well; but we can be sure that in either case the result will be either `true` or `false`. **If the result is `true`, *then* we'll get to this**:

```
this.showFunc()
```

**Otherwise**, the short-circuiting logic will have already resulted in a result of `false`. Hence the missing branch.

To be concrete: this scenario would occur if:

- `num` were greater than -1, AND:
- `position` were neither `"down"` nor `"up"`, OR:
- `position` were `"up`" but `value` were less than `this._offset`

The ternary expression covered this case, as does this answer. The other answers did not (the code would pass all the way through and result in `undefined`).

To be fair, though: the result isn't being used anyway (if the original code really is the one-liner you included) in which case there is no functional difference. However, I felt compelled to write this answer primarily to highlight the importance of testing any refactoring of existing functionality, even when the prior code is hideous and even when you've been careful in your analysis.

Comment: I didn't miss it, I just omitted it in the if-statement-logic :-) Technically, the OP doesn't `return` his expression so we don't know whether this is actually valid…

Comment: @Bergi: Well, to be fair, I didn't say *you* missed it, just that your answer did! Meaning, left it out (albeit on purpose in your case). You're right that there's no functional difference if the result is discarded (as it appears to be in the OP's example). I added a paragraph explaining my rationale for pointing this out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

@MajidL showed you what it is but not how to decipher it.

This is what's called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) and they can be very difficult to understand.

So to brake it down you have your first statement:

```
num > -1
```

This gets evaluated before anything else, if it's true it drops into a *second* ternary operator that is *also* combined with a `&&` operator:

```
"down" === position && value >= this._offset
```

Since this is also a ternary operator it has an `else` as well but that also happens to be an `if` check:

```
"up" === position && value >= this._offset
```

So you end up with this structure:

```
if(num > -1){
    if("down" === position && value >= this._offset){

    }else if("up" === position && value >= this._offset){

    }  
}else{

}
```

Which leaves you with figuring out what return values go with what checks. This is actually the tricky part IMO.

The last return value is actually the easiest, it will always belong to the `else` of the first ternary operator, as outer operators are considered first. So this:

```
this.showFunc();
```

Goes in to our structure like so:

```
if(num > -1){
    if("down" === position && value >= this._offset){

    }else if("up" === position && value >= this._offset){

    }  
}else{
    return this.showFunc();
}
```

Which leaves that middle check. Here is where your other developer did something sneaky and not very maintainable, he used the outer value as the return value for both ternary operations. I would not recommend doing this.

This also means that the inside value `this.hideFunc()` can only belong to the inner ternary operator and we end up with the completed statement.

```
if(num > -1){
    if("down" === position && value >= this._offset){
        return this.hideFunc();
    }else if("up" === position && value >= this._offset){
        return this.showFunc();
    }  
}else{
    return this.showFunc();
}
```